# How can I to categorize a timestamp column in an interval of 2 hours in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to categorize a column where the date is a DateTime field (timestamp) like the image below:

[image]

To do this, I need to create a new column in my DataFrame to receive the new data, where the result is a column categorized with interval 2 hours like the image above.

Result:

[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `floor_date`/`ceiling_date` from `lubridate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df <- data.frame(time = Sys.time() + sample(100000, 10))

df %>%
  mutate(interval = hour(floor_date(time, '2 hours')), 
         interval1 = paste(interval, interval + 2, sep = '-'), 
         interval2 = sprintf('[%d, %d)', interval, interval + 2, sep = '-'))

#                  time interval interval1 interval2
#1  2021-06-07 13:14:15       12     12-14  [12, 14)
#2  2021-06-07 14:57:42       14     14-16  [14, 16)
#3  2021-06-06 23:42:58       22     22-24  [22, 24)
#4  2021-06-07 07:11:57        6       6-8    [6, 8)
#5  2021-06-08 01:20:38        0       0-2    [0, 2)
#6  2021-06-07 17:51:25       16     16-18  [16, 18)
#7  2021-06-07 16:15:47       16     16-18  [16, 18)
#8  2021-06-07 11:29:56       10     10-12  [10, 12)
#9  2021-06-07 16:59:13       16     16-18  [16, 18)
#10 2021-06-07 11:47:07       10     10-12  [10, 12)
```

Comment: Hey @Ronak Shah, I am trying to understand the code. I see that you create a sample to use in df. In my case, I should use df['InvoiceDate'], right?

Comment: That's right. `df` is the dataframe name and `time` is the column name for me. Replace it according to your data. So `time` would be replaced with `InvoiceDate` for you.

Comment: I create my column datetime and used it to apply the transofrmation:

```rt_final['IntervalH'] <- rt_final$InvoiceDate
rt_final %>%
    mutate(interval = hour(floor_date(rt_final$IntervalH, '2 hours')),
           interval1 = paste(interval, interval + 2, sep = '-'),
           interval2 = sprintf('[%d, %d]', interval, interval + 2, sep='-'))
rt_final['IntervalH']
```

But an error happens:

```
Warning message:
Problem with `mutate()` column `interval2`.
ℹ `interval2 = sprintf("[%d, %d]", interval, interval + 2, sep = "-")`.
ℹ one argument not used by format '[%d, %d]' ```

Comment: @EricGomes  You are using slightly different code. Can you try `rt_final <- rt_final %>%
  mutate(intervalH = hour(floor_date(InvoiceDate, '2 hours')), 
         intervalH = sprintf('[%d, %d)', intervalH, intervalH + 2))`

Comment: Thanks @Ronak Shah, you help me a lot!

Comment: You are welcome. btw, Images are not the right way to share data since we cannot copy data from it to test our answers. You can use something like how I have used to generate fake dataset `df <- data.frame(time = Sys.time() + sample(100000, 10))` Or share part of your actual dataset with `dput` i.e share output of `dput(head(rt_final, 10))` so that we can copy and use it. You can  read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: Ok, I will better to the next question!